# Output GIF from ServletOutputStream

Tags: java, image, spring-mvc, servlets, gif

I'm writing an endpoint that dynamically generates a GIF file. I'll go from the ground up.

I have a class named `Function` that works like an abstract class and I have several classes, in this example `AddFunction`, that represent small chunks of functionality. In this case, the `AddFunction` adds some numbers together. When the end point is hit, the ID of the `AddFunction` is passed to it (it could be any, in this example it's the add function). The code in the controller is as follows:

```
/**
 * Returns the image for a function
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/function/{functionId}/image.gif", produces = "image/gif")
public void getImage(@PathVariable(value = "functionId") String functionId, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    Function function = functionService.getFunction(Integer.valueOf(functionId));

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FunctionController.class);

    ServletOutputStream servOut = response.getOutputStream();

    // Uses default values if you pass in nulls.
    function.getImage(servOut, null, null);

    servOut.flush();
    servOut.close();
}
```

First, the `Function` is found by it's ID. I have checked, and the correct function is being found. This code is in need of some validation (for example checking the id passed in is a valid number) but I'll get to that later. I then grab the servlet output stream and pass it to the `getImage` methods of the function. This method generates the GIF that describes the function. This code looks like this:

```
public void getImage(OutputStream out, String staticContent, String changedContent) throws IOException {
    String[] data = {"2", "+", "2", "=", "4"};

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AddFunction.class);

    logger.info("Getting the add image.");

    ImageUtils.writeSequenceToImage(ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(out), data, 5, Constants.IMAGE_HEIGHT / 2);
}
```

As you can see, it ignores the values and it is using stock data at the moment. It creates an array of values. Each of these values which appear in each frame of the GIF. So what I do is I take the `ServletOutputStream` and I use the `ImageIO.createImageOutputStream` to wrap that with an `ImageOutputStream` object. This is when passed into the `writeSequenceToImage` method in my own `ImageUtils` class. The last two values are coordinates for where to write from. In this case, the vertical middle of the image, on the far left. The code for the `writeSequenceToImage` method is as follows:

```
public static void writeSequenceToImage(ImageOutputStream out, String[] contentList, int x, int y) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder dataBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    Test test = new Test(out, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, 500, true);

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ImageUtils.class);

    logger.info("Writing sequence to image.");

    for (String content : contentList) {
        dataBuilder.append(content);

        logger.info("writing " + dataBuilder.toString() + " to the gif.");

        test.writeToSequence(generateAndWriteToImage(dataBuilder.toString(), x, y));
    }
}
```

In this code, I am using the class `Test` (temporary name) which contains code that writes data to a GIF file. All I'm doing here is looping through and adding each value to a frame in the GIF. The code for class `Test` can be found [here](http://elliot.kroo.net/software/java/GifSequenceWriter/). What I do is I build up the String, so in our example the logs would output:

```
2014-12-31 14:37:15 INFO  ImageUtils:48 - Writing sequence to image.
2014-12-31 14:37:15 INFO  ImageUtils:53 - writing 2 to the gif.
2014-12-31 14:37:15 INFO  ImageUtils:53 - writing 2+ to the gif.
2014-12-31 14:37:15 INFO  ImageUtils:53 - writing 2+2 to the gif.
2014-12-31 14:37:15 INFO  ImageUtils:53 - writing 2+2= to the gif.
2014-12-31 14:37:15 INFO  ImageUtils:53 - writing 2+2=4 to the gif.
```

This will give the appearance in each frame of the GIF of it building up the string. Now, I write this to the GIF and I expect it to be pushed straight into the `ServletOutputStream`, only when I attempt to reference it with the following HTML:

```
<div class="panel columns large-12" ng-show="selectedFunction">
    <h2>{{selectedFunction.name}}</h2>

    <p>{{selectedFunction.description}}</p>

    <p>This function expects a {{selectedFunction.expectedParameterType}} as a parameter.</p>

    <p>This function will return a {{selectedFunction.expectedReturnType}}</p>

    <img src="/autoalgorithm/functions/function/{{selectedFunction.id}}/image.gif" alt="{{selectedFunction.name}}"/>
</div>
```

I am seeing the following data returning in Chrome:

[image: Data Response]

And I am seeing no image on my page:

[image: View]

**What I have tried**

I've tried to see the size of what is coming back. To do this, I have replaced the `ServletOutputStream` with a `ByteArrayOutputStream` so I can get the size of the data. If I do this, my code looks like this:

```
/**
 * Returns the image for a function
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/function/{functionId}/image.gif", produces = "image/gif")
public @ResponseBody byte[] getImage(@PathVariable(value = "functionId") String functionId, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    Function function = functionService.getFunction(Integer.valueOf(functionId));

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FunctionController.class);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    // Uses default values if you pass in nulls.
    function.getImage(baos, null, null);

    logger.info("The number of bytes returned is " + baos.toByteArray().length);

    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

And the log outputs:

```
2014-12-31 15:34:09 INFO  FunctionController:85 - The number of bytes returned is 0
```

So that is telling me that it isn't being written too. So I changed up my approach and refactored the code so I maintained a reference to the `ImageOutputStream` in my controller. This meant that I had complete control over the object, so now the log outputted:

```
2014-12-31 15:39:56 INFO  FunctionController:85 - The number of bytes returned is 2708
```

Which was encouraging! And 2KB sounds about right for a very very simple GIF. However, when I check the response from Google, similar story:

[image: ios response]

Although this time it has a content length, but there is no preview available and the image still is not appearing.

I was wondering if anyone on here had tackled a similar issue? I suspect it is to do with the encoding of the GIF, but `ImageIO` doesn't support conversion from one stream to another, only from one `BufferedImage` type to another. So I used the `ImageIO.read` method to read it into a `BufferedImage` and used `ImageIO.write` to write it as a `gif` onto the `ServletOutputStream`. This yielded the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!
```

At this point, I'm stumped. I'm hoping a fresh set of eyes can help me out. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If you write the byte array as a gif file, can you open it and does render it properly? Also, why the content type is image/webp? Shouldn't be image/gif as annotated within the Controller method?

Comment: It *should* be. If no data is returned, it is coming up as `text/plain` which is even stranger! I'll have a test now and find out for you.

Comment: You're trying too much at once. That makes it difficult to sort out the problems. You probably have several ones. Create a test (separate from the Spring MVC framework) that saves the GIF in a file and verify that this works. Create a simpler controller method that reads a working GIF from disk and sends it as the response.

Comment: I can spot at least two problems: (1) You don't close the ImageOutputStream instance. Therefore, part of the image might be lost. (2) In your first version of the `getImage` method, you use both `HttpServletResponse` and `produces`. If I'm not mistaken, they don't mix. If you use `HttpServletResponse`, you have to set the content type and the content length in the response.

Comment: If you guys can provide a clear set of steps for A) Generating a GIF and B) Writing it in a HTTP Response then you'll get the bounty. I've not found this anywhere on Stack Overflow so I think it's important we get that down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already noted in the comments your question is a little bit unconcise but I'll try to show you how it can work.

**First try the following:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/function/{functionId}/image.gif", produces = "image/gif")
public void getImage(@PathVariable(value = "functionId") String functionId, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    BufferedImage firstImage = ImageIO.read(new File("/bla.jpg"));
    response.setContentType("image/gif"); // this should happen automatically

    ImageIO.write(firstImage, "gif", response.getOutputStream());
    response.getOutputStream().close();
}
```

Place some file named `bla.jpg` in your root directory or change the path to some existing image file (can also be a GIF). Make sure you have at least read access rights.

**This should work in any case, regardless if jpg or gif file. If this doesn't work there may be something wrong with your Spring configuration. You should rule that out.**

If this is working, you can use your method `generateAndWriteToImage()` to replace `ImageIO.read(new File("/bla.jpg"));`. And you should be done.

Now, I don't know what your `generateAndWriteToImage()` method does but I assume that it creates an instance of `BufferedImage`, writes some text into the image and returns it.
Something like this:

```
public static BufferedImage generateAndWriteToImage(String string, int x, int y) {

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(x,y,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    g.setPaintMode();
    g.setFont(g.getFont().deriveFont(30f));
    g.drawString(string, 100, 100);
    g.dispose();
    return image;
}
```

If you create the image with the type `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB` this shouldn't cause any problems.

**TL;DR** Another thing you already found out yourself is that a little refactoring gives you the ability to close the `ImageOutputStream`.

Assume the following method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/function/{functionId}/image.gif", produces = "image/gif")
public void getImage(@PathVariable(value = "functionId") String functionId, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    Function function = functionService.getFunction(Integer.valueOf(functionId));

    ServletOutputStream servOut = response.getOutputStream();

    // Uses default values if you pass in nulls.
    function.getImage(servOut, null, null);

    servOut.flush();
    servOut.close();
}
```

and this method:

```
public void getImage(OutputStream out, String staticContent, String changedContent) throws IOException {
    String[] data = {"2", "+", "2", "=", "4"};

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AddFunction.class);

    logger.info("Getting the add image.");

    ImageUtils.writeSequenceToImage(ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(out), data, 5, Constants.IMAGE_HEIGHT / 2);
}
```

In the second method, you are creating a local instance of `ImageOutputStream` with `ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(out)` (last line).

I guess the main problem is, that you aren't closing this `ImageOutputStream`, this may result in data not beeing written to any other `OutputStream` (because of buffering).

To make it work you can refactor your methods to this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/function/{functionId}/image.gif", produces = "image/gif")
public void getImage(@PathVariable(value = "functionId") String functionId, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    Function function = functionService.getFunction(Integer.valueOf(functionId));

    ImageOutputStream servOut = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

    // Uses default values if you pass in nulls.
    function.getImage(servOut, null, null);

    servOut.close();
}
```

and this:

```
public void getImage(ImageOutputStream out, String staticContent, String changedContent) throws IOException {
    String[] data = {"2", "+", "2", "=", "4"};

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AddFunction.class);

    logger.info("Getting the add image.");

    ImageUtils.writeSequenceToImage(out, data, 5, Constants.IMAGE_HEIGHT / 2);
}
```

The same thing applies here for the `generateAndWriteToImage()` method. If it correctly returns an instance of `BufferedImage`, this should work (with the refactoring).

Comment: Your tips lead me to the correct answer and I feel that this is a really good guide for anyone returning to this question. Well earnt!

Answer (score 0):

I did not try with spring but tried with J2EE instead. Below approach works for me !

```
private void process(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {

    String baseServletPath = httpServletRequest.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");

    System.out.println("Base Servlet Path :"+baseServletPath);
    String relativeInputFilePath = "images/Tulips.gif";
    String imageFilePath = baseServletPath + relativeInputFilePath;
    File file = new File(imageFilePath);

    BufferedImage bufferedImage = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(file);
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "GIF", byteArrayOutputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    byte[] imageData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    String relativeOutFilePath = "images/TulipsOut.gif";
    String imageOutFilePath = baseServletPath + relativeOutFilePath;
    File fileOut = new File(imageOutFilePath);
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream=null;
    try {
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileOut);
        fileOutputStream.write(imageData);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    try {
        httpServletResponse.getOutputStream().write( imageData );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, the problem with this approach is that you're getting a GIF from a file and outputting it in the response. I'm looking for how to generate it with code.

Comment: I was just trying to help with the broken image part. That's all. There should be a few tutorials and examples for you to learn how to create an image in java. Like [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html)

Comment: No I agree, your input was good. But what I was looking for was a complete, self contained, step by step explanation of the problem. That was provided above, in a nice "troubleshooting" format. All the same, +1 for the valid information. Edit: By the way, I didn't downvote.