# Java Eclipse - Problems saving GIF to file from servlet

Tags: java, gif, animated-gif, javax.imageio, fileoutputstream

Im doing a simple animated gif in Eclipse Mars as an assignment and part of the assignment is that the user should be able to influence the animation in some sort of way through a webpage and therefore has to be made in a servlet. So Ive created input parameters for the user to influence the color of 7 moving rectangles "falling" over a black background. Anyway, the problem is that when I run my code, it doesn't save the the gif to the FileOutputStream for some reason but doesn't give an error message or anything. I created another animation in a test version without the user being able to influence the colors and then it works perfectly fine. The file is saved overtime then so Ive used the same method to save it in the servlet but for some reason it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import net.jmge.gif.Gif89Encoder;

@WebServlet("/Animation")
public class Animation extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Animation() {
        super();
    }

    static void drawFrame(Graphics2D g, int frame, Color c1, Color c2, Color c3, Color c4, Color c5, Color c6, Color c7){
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 150);
        g.setColor(c1);
        g.fillRect(0,8*frame-20,50,20);
        g.setColor(c2);
        g.fillRect(50,8*frame-20,50,20);
        g.setColor(c3);
        g.fillRect(50,8*frame-40,50,20);
        g.setColor(c4);
        g.fillRect(50,8*frame-60,50,20);
        g.setColor(c5);
        g.fillRect(50,8*frame-80,50,20);
        g.setColor(c6);
        g.fillRect(50,8*frame-100,50,20);
        g.setColor(c7);
        g.fillRect(50,8*frame-120,50,20);
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (request.getParameter("c1") == null){
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("<form>");
            out.println("Color 1: <input name='c1' value='1FEA00'/><br>");
            out.println("Color 2: <input name='c2' value='FFFF00'/><br>");
            out.println("Color 3: <input name='c3' value='FF9000'/><br>");
            out.println("Color 4: <input name='c4' value='FF0000'/><br>");
            out.println("Color 5: <input name='c5' value='F000FF'/><br>");
            out.println("Color 6: <input name='c6' value='9600FF'/><br>");
            out.println("Color 7: <input name='c7' value='0000FF'/><br>");
            out.println("<input type = 'submit'/>");
            out.println("</form>");

        }else{
            Color c1 = new Color(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("c1"),16));
            Color c2 = new Color(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("c2"),16));
            Color c3 = new Color(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("c3"),16));
            Color c4 = new Color(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("c4"),16));
            Color c5 = new Color(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("c5"),16));
            Color c6 = new Color(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("c6"),16));
            Color c7 = new Color(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("c7"),16));

            try {
                response.setContentType("image/gif");
                Gif89Encoder genc = new Gif89Encoder();
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("animation1.gif");
                for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
                {
                    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(700,100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                    Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
                    drawFrame(g,i,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7);
                    genc.addFrame(image);
                    g.dispose();
                    ImageIO.write(image, "gif", response.getOutputStream());
                }
                genc.setUniformDelay(10);
                genc.setLoopCount(0);
                genc.encode(out);
                out.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would be so thankful for any help!

Comment: See [Output GIF from ServletOutputStream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723315/output-gif-from-servletoutputstream) or [writing image to a jsp from database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899591/writing-image-to-a-jsp-from-database)

Comment: Why are you creating multiple GIFs? You are storing each frame in the loop, to the servlet response as a full standalone file using `ImageIO.write`, but writing another (animated) to a file using `Gif89Encoder`. Is this intentional?